# Apache VirtualHost - redirect from one domain to a specific page of another one *transparently*

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

I would like to redirect `www.example.it` to `www.example.com/index-it.php`

The website is just a one-page site.

I would like that to happen transparently, in the sense that www.example.it will be still displayed on the address bar after the redirect.

I have tried this but it generates an Internal Server Error.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.it

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/.*$ http://www..com/index-it.php [P,L]

</VirtualHost>
```

This would work instead, *but* it doesn't provide a transparent redirect:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.it

RewriteEngine on
#RewriteRule ^/.*$ http://www.example.com/index-it.php [P,L]

Redirect 301 / http://www.example.com/index-it.php

</VirtualHost>
```

Any idea, please?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a silly problem: mod_proxy wasn't enabled

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you don't actually want to redirect, because "redirect" actually means "tell the browser to request this other page instead."

Also, I'm betting you don't actually want to redirect *all* requests, because if your browser URL bar shows `www.example.it` and the page it has loaded has a reference to `/logo.png`, the browser will request `http://www.example.it/logo.png` and it will be surprised to get the output of `www.example.com/index-it.php` in response.

Because you're using the `[P]` flag, the approach you're actually taking is *reverse proxing* all requests to `www.example.it` to `www.example.com`, and before proxying, internally rewrite some subset of index requests on `www.example.it` to `/index-it.php`. The [When Not To Use Rewrite](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite) page lists "proxying" as one of its times not to use `mod_rewrite`. [`mod_proxy`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html) by itself wil help you with the proxying; `mod_rewrite`'s documentation actually suggests preferring `mod_proxy` directives over the `P` flag.

Read `mod_proxy`'s  warning about being sure your server is secure before you turn it on. The index-file juggling may be a reasonable use of `mod_rewrite`, but it doesn't require use of the `P` flag.

Comment: I think I am already using mod_proxy as I am using P as a flag. Please see here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: That leads to two more questions, then: Are you sure `mod_proxy` is enabled? And, why use the `P` flag over just using `mod_proxy`'s directives, when the `mod_rewrite` documentation says, "Avoid using this flag and prefer those directives, whenever you can."? (You may have a good reason, I'm just not seeing it in your question.)

Comment: @dan Your problem is solved, but for others who may get here later via search I've edited my answer to include [my favorite link for Server Fault](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite).